# How to call "overriden" methods from both parent classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, multiple-inheritance, super

Consider the following classes where `P1` and `P2` are parent classes of `C`:

```py
class P1:
    def f(self):
        print('P1')


class P2:
    def f(self):
        print('P2')


class C(P1, P2):
    def f(self):
        print('C')
        # super().f()
        # super(P1, self).f()

c = C()
c.f()
```

When I run this, it prints `C`.

If I uncomment the first line, `super().f()`, then it'll also print `P1`
because `super()` will call the method from the direct parent, `P1`

And if I uncomment the second line, `super(P1, self).f()`, then it'll also print `P2`
because `super(P1, self)` will call the method from `P1`'s sibling, `P2`

What I want to know is that if there is any way to call `f` methods from both of the parent classes `P1` and `P2` with a single call of `super()` function, rather than calling it twice as I did.

Or, are there any other ways to do that without using `super` function?

Comment: There's no language feature to do it; it's an uncommon desire.  For the rare cases where you do want to call overridden methods in all parent classes, it's better to just do it explicitly: it'd be more readable, and the behavior (e.g. ordering) would be clearly defined.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for your feedback. I was just curious. It is not what I "desire".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super calls the next method from the method resolution order(MRO) of the derived class.

Every implementation of the method f should call super, the parent classes do not need to know about each other, super will automaticly call the next method in the MRO.

Edit: I forgot that the last class in the mro is always object.
object has no method called f. so you should take care that the last class in the mro that has that method, either does not call super().f or catches the AttributeError.

As long as you follow the C3 linearization rules, The child class can change the MRO. This means the derived class determins what code gets run and what code does not get run. This is one way of dependancy injection.

You can inspect the MRO of a class by the __mro__ atribute.

This answer is mostly based on the talk [super considered super](https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo) by Raymond Hettinger

```
class P1:
    def f(self):
        super().f()
        print('P1')

class P2:
    def f(self):
        print('P2')

class C(P1, P2):
    def f(self):
        super().f()
        print('C')

class C2(P2, P1):
    def f(self):
        super().f()
        print('C2')

>>> C().f()
P2
P1
C
>>> C2().f()
P2
C2
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.P1'>, <class '__main__.P2'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> C2.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C2'>, <class '__main__.P2'>, <class '__main__.P1'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Comment: It looks like the code works without `super` call in `P2`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the output you show here. When I call `C().f()`, I get an `AttributeError`, when it tries to find `object.f` (which obviously doesn't exist).

Comment: @oldwooki: Without a `super` call in `P2`, you can't inherit in a different order. If you declared `class C2(P2, P1)`, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Blckknght I had forgotten that object was the base class. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @oldwooki you can omit super in P2 but then C1.f is not called when you change the MRO. See my updayed answer.

Comment: Right, it's not gonna work if the inheritance order is changed.

Answer (score 3):

There's no good way to do exactly what you want. But if you can modify both `P1` and `P2`, you can implement collaborative multiple inheritance, you just need to add a base class to both of the parent classes that has a no-op implementation of the method:

```
class GP: # grandparent base class
    def f(self):
        pass  # do nothing

class P1(GP):
    def f(self):
        print("P1")
        super().f()

class P2(GP):
    def f(self):
        print("P2")
        super().f()

class C(P1, P2):
    def f(self):
        print("C")
        super().f()
```

This works because `super` doesn't exactly mean "my parent class". It means "next in the MRO' for this object". The MRO is the Method Resolution Order, basically the order things are searched for in inheritance. When `super()` is called in `C`, it finds the method in `P1`. But when `super()` is called in `P1` (on an instance of `C`), it calls `P2`, since the MRO of a `C` instance is `[C, P1, P2, GP, object]`. `P2` comes after `P1`, so it gets picked by the second `super` call.

The `GP` class is needed to end the chain of `super` calls. If you didn't have it, the last `super` call would resolve to `object` (which is the root of all inheritance trees) and since there's no such method, you'd get an error. The implementation in the base class doesn't need to do nothing, it just needs to not call `super` at the end.

Comment: It looks like it would work without the `GP` class.

Comment: @oldwooki if you remove the GP base class then you get the problem in my answer where P2 calls object.f, resulting in an AttributeError. And removing the call in P2 means you wont call P1 if you put P2 earlier in the MRO.

Comment: @steviestickman I get what you are saying, but let me rephrase, it worked without the `GP` class when I tried. It printed `C`, `P1`, P2` without raising an `AttributeError`